# exc bad access code 2

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiviewcontroller, uitableview, ipad-2

I have been struggling with this error for the last 3 days and no luck. I'm developing a combined app with `uiviewcontrollers` and `uitableviewcontrollers` and in table views I click the add button and it crashes. (no core data coding has been added yet). I have even enabled `NSzombies` and `Guard Malloc` and the following points of crashing are on these codes. Please help as I need to try chase a deadline and I don't want to go further in development with the gremlin in the project.

```
0x0 into
0x93e3bef3 testl
0x93e3570c movl
0x1f1b124 testl
0x1f18eb1 movl
0x8fecf203 addl
0x8feced68 movl
0x8fecc2c8 movb
0x8fecc25e movl
0x8fecc25e movl
0x8fecc25e movl
0x8fecc25e movl
0x8fecd268 movl
0x8fec1664 addl
0x8fec5f99 jmp
0x8febf2ef addl
```

Comment: You will need to symbolicate the stack trace and show us the relevant source; would you expect anyone to recognize that assembler?

Comment: Use breakpoint and check what's wrong.. and as @trojanfoe has told you we are not assemblers

Answer (score 25):

Use the "Zombie" tool in Instruments.

Open menu Product > Profile. Xcode opens instruments, where you can select a tool. Select Zombie. The app will open in simulator then recreate the EXC_BAD_ACCESS error. Instruments will show you what variable and on what function raised this error.

Comment: Thank you! Using the Zombie pointed me to right place! found but straight away!

Comment: How to do that when the error appears when I am unit testing a class?

Comment: Frankly, I don't have experience in working Instruments with unit testing. You can try manually attach Instrument (Zombie tool) to app process...

Comment: @idmean It doesn't show the function or variable, where can I access it?

Comment: @ChanchalRaj this branch will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14636028/understanding-zombie-trace-in-instruments