# Understanding zombie trace in Instruments

Tags: iphone, ios, instruments, nszombie, zombie-process

I am kind of new at ios development and my app crashes because of EXEC_BAD_ACCESS. 
To detect problem i enabled Zombies and trace Allocations by using Instruments in xCode 4.5
After it detects Zombie Messaged i am having trouble to find which part of code crashes.

Here is the instruments screen shot: 
[image]
Thanks for any help.

Comment: I don't know about Instruments, but you can add a breakpoint to catch all exceptions in Xcode.  In the Breakpoints tab, in the bottom left corner there is a plus button.  You can add the Exception Breakpoint and see where the exception occurs, if not why.

Comment: Are you using ARC? It should prevent most of these errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also have the problem at the beginning of learning Instruments, then I figured out the I have to open the 'Extended detail' Pane to see it.(There might other easy way to enable this, but I did not find yet)

[image: How to find which line of code crashes using Zombie instruments]

Answer (score 2):

It could be interesting to see your code? you might be running some tasks which are causing memory leaks or bad access, e.g; calling some UI related task in background thread. recently in IOS6 had issue with showing alerts with calling `[alert show];`, if you have the similar scenario then you could replace this show method something like this.

```
[alert performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(show) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];
```

if this is not the issue then you might show your code and someone could help you better that way.