# EXC_BAD_ACCESS Code 2 on CCCrypt

Tags: ios, encryption, ios7.1, des

I am trying to use `DES` encryption to encrypt passwords (Don't ask why DES, I know it's less secure). I am doing it for the first time in iOS, thus had to rely on another post about how to do it.

When I run the encryption it returns null, same with decrypting an already encrypted string(I used an online tool to encrypt). When I put a breakpoint to see what is going on, it stopped at `CCCrypt` mentioning `EXC_BAD_ACCESS (Code 2)`.

I tried using different CCOptions, but it returns the same thing always. 
Any hint what's going wrong? Is iv string required?

I have used the following NSString category to encrypt or decrypt Strings -

```
#import "NSString+DES.h"

@implementation NSString(DES)

- (NSString*) encryptDES: (NSString *) key
{
    const void *vplainText;
    size_t plainTextBufferSize;

    plainTextBufferSize = [self length];
    vplainText = (const void *) [self UTF8String];

    CCCryptorStatus ccStatus;
    uint8_t *bufferPtr = NULL;
    size_t bufferPtrSize = 0;
    size_t *movedBytes;

    bufferPtrSize = (plainTextBufferSize + kCCBlockSize3DES) & ~(kCCBlockSize3DES - 1);
    bufferPtr = malloc( bufferPtrSize * sizeof(uint8_t));
    memset((void *)bufferPtr, 0x0, bufferPtrSize);
    // memset((void *) iv, 0x0, (size_t) sizeof(iv));


    //NSString *initVec = @"init Vec";
    const void *vkey = (const void *) [key UTF8String];
    //const void *vinitVec = (const void *) [initVec UTF8String];

    ccStatus = CCCrypt(kCCEncrypt,
                       kCCAlgorithmDES,
                       kCCOptionPKCS7Padding | kCCOptionECBMode,
                       vkey,
                       kCCKeySizeDES,
                       NULL,
                       vplainText,
                       plainTextBufferSize,
                       (void *)bufferPtr,
                       bufferPtrSize,
                       movedBytes);

    NSString *result;
    NSData *myData = [NSData dataWithBytes:(const void *)bufferPtr length:(NSUInteger)movedBytes];
    result = [myData base64EncodedStringWithOptions:NSDataBase64Encoding64CharacterLineLength];
    return result;
}

- (NSString *) decryptDES: (NSString *) key
{
    const void *vplainText;
    size_t plainTextBufferSize;

    plainTextBufferSize = [self length];
    vplainText = (const void *) [self UTF8String];

    CCCryptorStatus ccStatus;
    uint8_t *bufferPtr = NULL;
    size_t bufferPtrSize = 0;
    size_t *movedBytes;

    bufferPtrSize = (plainTextBufferSize + kCCBlockSize3DES) & ~(kCCBlockSize3DES - 1);
    bufferPtr = malloc( bufferPtrSize * sizeof(uint8_t));
    memset((void *)bufferPtr, 0x0, bufferPtrSize);
    // memset((void *) iv, 0x0, (size_t) sizeof(iv));


    //NSString *initVec = @"init Vec";
    const void *vkey = (const void *) [key UTF8String];
    //const void *vinitVec = (const void *) [initVec UTF8String];

    ccStatus = CCCrypt(kCCDecrypt,
                       kCCAlgorithmDES,
                       kCCOptionPKCS7Padding | kCCOptionECBMode,
                       vkey, //"123456789012345678901234", //key
                       kCCKeySizeDES,
                       NULL,// vinitVec, //"init Vec", //iv,
                       vplainText, //"Your Name", //plainText,
                       plainTextBufferSize,
                       (void *)bufferPtr,
                       bufferPtrSize,
                       movedBytes);

    NSString *result;
    NSData *myData = [NSData dataWithBytes:(const void *)bufferPtr length:(NSUInteger)movedBytes];
    result = [myData base64EncodedStringWithOptions:NSDataBase64Encoding64CharacterLineLength];
    return result;
}

@end
```

**Update:**

I have checked few more places and changed the code a little bit, the encryption works but doesn't get decrypted with correct value.

For example when I use `YourName` as string and `12345` as the key, I get `Fu2sK61e7l5rkXRhAKjPWA==` as the encrypted code, but the decryption returns `+54qWCYTB5LkdARDZjAow==` and not `YourName`.

**Updated Code:**

```
#import "NSString+DES.h"

@implementation NSString(DES)

- (NSString*) encryptDES: (NSString *) key
{
    NSData *keyData = [key dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSData *stringData = [self dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    size_t numBytesEncrypted = 0;
    size_t bufferSize = stringData.length + kCCBlockSizeDES;
    void *buffer = malloc(bufferSize);

    CCCryptorStatus result = CCCrypt( kCCEncrypt, kCCAlgorithmDES, kCCOptionPKCS7Padding,
                                     keyData.bytes, kCCKeySizeDES,
                                     NULL,
                                     stringData.bytes, stringData.length,
                                     buffer, bufferSize,
                                     &numBytesEncrypted);
    NSData *output = [NSData dataWithBytes:buffer length:numBytesEncrypted];
    free(buffer);
    if( result == kCCSuccess )
    {
        NSString *resultStr = [output base64EncodedStringWithOptions:NSDataBase64Encoding64CharacterLineLength];
        return resultStr;
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Failed DES encrypt...");
        return nil;
    }

}

- (NSString *) decryptDES: (NSString *) key
{
    NSData *keyData = [key dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSData *stringData = [[NSData alloc] initWithBase64EncodedString:self options:0];

    size_t numBytesEncrypted = 0;
    size_t bufferSize = stringData.length + kCCBlockSizeDES;
    void *buffer = malloc(bufferSize);

    CCCryptorStatus result = CCCrypt( kCCDecrypt, kCCAlgorithmDES, kCCOptionPKCS7Padding,
                                     keyData.bytes, kCCKeySizeDES,
                                     NULL,
                                     stringData.bytes, stringData.length,
                                     buffer, bufferSize,
                                     &numBytesEncrypted);
    NSData *output = [NSData dataWithBytes:buffer length:numBytesEncrypted];
    free(buffer);
    if( result == kCCSuccess )
    {
        NSString *resultStr = [output base64EncodedStringWithOptions:NSDataBase64Encoding64CharacterLineLength];
        return resultStr;
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Failed DES decrypt...");
        return nil;
    }
}

@end
```

Comment: @Bhavin 'ccStatus = CCCrypt(...);' is the culprit here.

Comment: ok..had you check this link...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11717193/exc-bad-access-code-2

Comment: ECB mode does not use an iv.

Comment: The key needs to be exactly 8-bytes for DES, if it is to short the result will be undefined. In the updated code the key is 5-bytes but the length is given as 8-bytes (`kCCKeySizeDES`) so the three missing key bytes will be whatever bytes follow `keyData`.

Comment: Note that in the updated answer you did not specify ECB mode, the default is CBC mode. You need to add `kCCOptionECBMode`.

Comment: With the two above changes to the update code (key=12345679 and ECB Mode) it will produce the same result as my answer.

Comment: @Zaph Thanks for the comments. This actually solves the encryption part in both the code. But the decryption is not working. I am getting `9Bo4VzSXN4CePfTX2pdtVnrwJIR6plUR` in first code while getting `WW91ciBOYW1l` in second code after decryption. I guess that's related base64 decoding.

Comment: In decrypt you do not want to Base64 encode, you want to convert the data to a `NSString`: `NSString * resultStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:output encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];`

Comment: Note: If you are using an online encryption that uses the php mcrypt function the last block of the data will be incorrect because mcrypt does not support PKCS#7 padding, it uses non-standard and insecure null padding.

Comment: @Zaph Thanks a ton for your help. Decryption is working in second method, but not in first one. The first one returns null string. But that's enough for me.
On a second note, can you also post these comments in your answer too? That would help out others too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be general confusion about the algorithm, DES or 3DES, a mix is being used but the key is 3DES (24-bytes). The key needs to be changed to 8-bytes. The block size constant should also be changed to `kCCBlockSizeDES` but that does not cause an error since it is the same value.

For the method:

```
- (NSString *) decryptDES: (NSString *) key
```

The bad access error is caused because no storage is allocated for `movedBytes`, just a pointer. Change the declaration to:

```
size_t movedBytes;
```

Change the reference to `movedBytes` in `CCCrypt` to `&movedBytes`.

Test output for encryption:

> string: "Your Name"
> key: "12345678"
>
> movedBytes: 16
> myData: 136142f6 6cd98e01 af1eef46 28d36499
> result: E2FC9mzZjgGvHu9GKNNkmQ==

Notes from comments by request:

ECB mode does not use an iv.

The key needs to be exactly 8-bytes for DES, if it is to short the result will be undefined. In the updated code the key is 5-bytes but the length is given as 8-bytes (`kCCKeySizeDES`) so the three missing key bytes will be whatever bytes follow `keyData`.

The updated answer did not specify ECB mode, the default is CBC mode. Add `kCCOptionECBMode`.

In decrypt do not use Base64 encode, convert the data to a `NSString`:

```
NSString * resultStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:output encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

If using an online encryption that uses the php mcrypt function the last block of the data will be incorrect because mcrypt does not support PKCS#7 padding, it uses non-standard and insecure null padding.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However I need DES algorithm only since there's already some encrypted data which I need to decrypt too. Apart from that I checked the result from online tools and it doesn't seem to match. I am using this tool - http://codebeautify.org/encrypt-decrypt