# My quickSort() program cannot work well, why?

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, debugging, quicksort

If you can help me, really thanks! Below is my code to sort vectors of numbers (of type double). The number of elements in vec is 200,000.

The program stopped at the green line, after several seconds. The error message is that

> "Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code = 2, address=0x7fff5f3fffd8)".

just like the picture:

[image]

```
/*This is block to call quickSort*/
void VectorDoubleSort:: sort(std::vector<double>& vec){
      int start = 0;
      int end = vec.size() - 1;
      quickSort(vec, start, end);
}




/*This block to fulfill the quickSort method*/
    void VectorDoubleSort:: quickSort(std::vector<double>& vec, int start, int end)
    {
        int pivot = (start + end) / 2;
        int smallIndex = start;

        if (start < end) {
            double tempA = vec[start];
            vec[pivot] = tempA;

            for (int i = start + 1; i <= end; i++) {
                if (vec[i] <= vec[start]) {
                    smallIndex += 1;
                    double tempB = vec[i];
                    vec[i] = vec[smallIndex];
                    vec[smallIndex] = tempB;
                }
            }

            double tempC = vec[start];
            vec[start] = vec[smallIndex];
            vec[smallIndex] = tempC;

            pivot = smallIndex;

            quickSort(vec, start, pivot - 1);
            quickSort(vec, pivot + 1, end);
        }
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean can't work well? Provide information in the question instead of expecting us to glean it from the image.

Comment: The process stopped at the green line, I can not find the reason. It is really frustrated.

Comment: Usually you should include the textual error message in the question, rather than showing a screenshot.

Comment: The error message is that "Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code = 2, address=0x7fff5f3fffd8)". The program stopped at the green line.

Comment: @WBLee Use **Zombie** tool in **Insturments** to find out the cause of the problem, more details: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11717981/2128327

Comment: Presumably a duff parameter, then.

Comment: @ Khaled A Khunaifer Thanks for the information about zombie toll!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, here is wrong:

```
int pivot = (start + end) / 2;
double tempA = vec[start];
vec[pivot] = tempA;
```

you lost content of `vec[pivot]`, after that here `if (vec[i] <= vec[start])` you
order your vector by value of `vec[start]`, then `pivot` is start, then why the hell,
you set pivot to  `(start + end) / 2;`? And as you use in compare **NOT** saved
value, but reread it from `vec[start]`, which can be changed by `swap` operation in vector. And after all you order against `start`, but your index increased in ordering cycle `for (int i = start + 1; i <= end; i++)`, so after iteration you
have (of course if previous bugs was fixed):
{`pivot`, `sub array <= pivot`, `sub array > pivot`}, so you need instead of just `swap` if do index from `end` to `start + 1` you need move  `sub array <= pivot` to  `start` and insert `pivot` between,
so the right solution if reuse as much your code is possible will be:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <cassert>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>

namespace VectorDoubleSort {
void sort(std::vector<double> &vec);
void quickSort(std::vector<double> &vec, int start, int end);
}

void VectorDoubleSort::sort(std::vector<double> &vec) {
  if (vec.empty())
    return;
  int start = 0;
  int end = vec.size() - 1;
  quickSort(vec, start, end);
}

/*This block to fulfill the quickSort method*/
void VectorDoubleSort::quickSort(std::vector<double> &vec, int start, int end) {
  if (start < end) {
    const double pivotVal = vec[start];
    int smallIndex = end;

    for (int i = end; i > start; --i) {
      if (vec[i] >= pivotVal) {
        std::swap(vec[i], vec[smallIndex]);
        --smallIndex;
      }
    }
    std::swap(vec[start], vec[smallIndex]);

    const int pivot = smallIndex;
    quickSort(vec, start, pivot - 1);
    quickSort(vec, pivot + 1, end);
  }
}

bool test(const std::vector<double> &arr) {
  std::vector<double> good = arr;
  std::sort(good.begin(), good.end());
  std::vector<double> my = arr;
  VectorDoubleSort::sort(my);
  std::copy(my.begin(), my.end(),
            std::ostream_iterator<double>(std::cout, ", "));
  std::cout << "\n";
  return my == good;
}

int main() {
  assert(test({}));
  assert(test({3., 1., 2., 17., 18., -1., -5.}));
  assert(test({3., 1., 2.}));
  assert(test({3., 2.}));
  assert(test({3.}));
  assert(test({3., 532523, 5235, 05325, 535, 5738157, 535, 501, 9780, 14}));
}
```

**Note:** I use `c++11`(initializer_list), but only for testing, so without tests you can reuse `c++98` or `c++03`